# Is a triangle with 4 verts considered a quad?

Tags: geometry

I was curious to know whether or not this shape is considered a quad or not?

[image: Is this a quad]

Considering it is in the shape of a triangle but contains 4 verts, I wasn't sure whether it would be considered a tris or a quad.

Comment: The polygon has four edges. So it is a quad. How the vertices are arranged doesn't matter.

Comment: Also a good way to tell is if you try to create loop cuts, as you can only do loop cuts on quad geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a quad, even if two of the edges are exactly in a line. If, for example, you were to use triangulate (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> while in Edit mode) you would find that it was split into two tris (hopefully from the bottom right point to the middle left one).

I generally find making tris into quads like this makes for a messier model, though, unless there is a reason for it. If it works with your mesh, then go for it, but if you are just doing something like this to have quads, I don't think it's a great idea (feel free to correct me if you think I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is even a "trick" used sometimes that when you get a triangle you just add a cut going to one of its edges and get a "triangular" quad.